# SwitchListTile background color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using this lightTheme and darkTheme and I would like to have the same background color for the SwitchListTile( white SwitchListTile background for lightTheme theme and RGB(27, 39, 55, 1.0) SwitchListTile background for darkTheme )

```
 lightTheme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE5E5E5),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        accentColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        dividerColor: Colors.white54,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(27, 39, 55, 1.0),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF212121),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(27, 39, 55, 1.0),
        accentColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        dividerColor: Colors.black12,
      ),
```

I'm using lutter_settings_screens package

```
Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    child: SettingsGroup(
                      title: 'settings',
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SettingsContainer(
                          children: [
                            SwitchSettingsTile(
                              defaultValue: true,
                              settingKey: 'switch1',
                              title: 'switch1',
                              subtitle: 'switch1',
                              onChange: (value) {},
                            ),
                            SwitchSettingsTile(
                              defaultValue: true,
                              settingKey: 'switch2',
                              title: 'switch2',
                              subtitle: 'switch2',
                              onChange: (value) {},
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
```

so which params I missed in ThemeData or in SwitchListTile to achieve this ? attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VdeV.png)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VdeV.png)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you were looking for, and quite frankly I do not know which theme property changes `SwitchListTile` background color, but changing theme property value might affect some other UI color as well, so you might want to update only the SwitchListTile color like this:

```
Ink(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: SwitchListTile(
    value: false,
    title: Text('Switch'),
    onChanged: (val) {},
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks @dshukertjr, I'm using SwitchSettingsTile from lutter_settings_screens package, I have check this package there is no override of color, so this is why I'm suspecting something in ThemeData ( not sure ), I have test what your suggest on  SettingsGroup, SettingsContainer and SwitchSettingsTile it's not working, I have update topic with example

Comment: override background color does not work because those widgets (  SettingsGroup, SettingsContainer and SwitchSettings) are Wrap inside Material in this package, I have edit package and remove Material from those widget and now It's work, so do you know how we can set Default color for Material Widget per Theme ?